# How to include symbols in flextable?

Tags: r, flextable

### Problem

I want to include symbols that represent parameters in a `flextable`. Following is an example:

```
library(flextable)


params_names <- c("T", "A_i", "b", "delta", "s_0")


params_values <- c(0.97, 3.83, 2.83, 1.29, 1.07)



data_tab <- data.frame(Parameter = params_names,
                       Value = params_values)


ft <- flextable(data_tab)
```

#### Current Output

[image]

#### Desired Output

I created the following desired output in Word:

[image]

#### What I tried

I tried using the `Tex` function from `latex2exp` package, and also the `mkpar` from `flextable` package. But I do not get the desired output. Please guide me how can I change the current output to the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```r
library(flextable)
# equatags::mathjax_install()
params_names <- c("T", "A_i", "b", "\\Delta", "s_0")
params_values <- c(0.97, 3.83, 2.83, 1.29, 1.07)

data_tab <- data.frame(Parameter = params_names,
                       Value = params_values)

ft <- flextable(data_tab)
ft <- compose(ft, j = "Parameter", value = as_paragraph(as_equation(Parameter)))
ft
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! For anyone doing the same thing, I had to install node js first and then `equatags::mathjax_install()`.